# How can I add a f(x) as an argument on Python function?

Tags: python, function, max

I'm trying to find the maximum of any function f(x) in a certain range and in which x this happens. The arguments of the python function would be (f(x),[a,b]). f(x) being any function and [a,b] the range we will be studying.

For now I've tried a few things but none of them worked. The one I liked the most was a failure because of trying to convert a string onto a float.

```
def maxf(function,interval):
  maxresult = 0
  for x in range(interval[0]-1,interval[1]+1):
    result=float(function.replace("x",str(x)))
    if result >= maxresult:
      maxresult = result
      maxresultx = x

  return maxresult,maxresultx
print(maxf("x**2",[1,3]))
```

This one returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(maxf("x**2",[1,3]))
  File "main.py", line 4, in maxf
    result=float(function.replace("x",str(x)))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0**2'
```

I don't know if there is an easier way to do it or how to correct the code so that I can convert that string.

Comment: The error is because you should evaluate the string, which is a little more complicated than calling `float`. So if you replace `float` by `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval` because eval is a security issue), your code will be working.  However, a better and faster solution could involve `numpy.argmax`. It depends whether you are learning how to do this, or looking for a performant solution.

Comment: The solution using lambda is really the cleanest. eval() is just an ugly hack in any programming language. You get all sorts of issues with eval().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your string is not actually being evaluated. It is just being converted to float so as the error suggests what you are doing is converting "0**2" to float which is not possible what you can do is make use of eval function to evaluate any given string and then compare the result.

You just need to make a small change like this:

```
result=eval(function.replace("x",str(x)))
```

This yet not the best way to do this you should use generator there:

```
def maxf(function,interval):
  maxresult = 0
  for x in range(interval[0]-1,interval[1]+1):
    yield eval(function.replace("x",str(x))), x


print(max(maxf("x**2", [1, 3])))
```

A more pythonic approach would be using lambda with max function as a key

```
a_list = [1,3]

max_item = max(a_list, key=lambda x: eval("x**2"))

print(eval("x**2".replace("x", str(max_item))), max_item)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `float()` accepts a string that *already represents a float* (eg `float("1.23")`, not an expression that will result in one (eg `float("2**3")`). So, you must first evaluate the string.

```py
float(eval("3**2"))
```

> `eval()` will run any code contained in the string, so don't use it on code you don't trust.

Comment: He wants max of "any" function

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
def maxf(function,interval):
  maxresult = 0
  for x in range(interval[0]-1,interval[1]+1):
    result=float(function(x))
    if result >= maxresult:
      maxresult = result
      maxresultx = x

  return maxresult,maxresultx
print(maxf(lambda x: x**2,[1,3]))
```

`lambda` defines a function (an anonymous one) that is passed as parameter, thus `maxf` can call it as needed.

Python is (also) a functional language, which means that you can use functions as you use ints or floats, etc. A function is just a bunch of callable code, you can associate an identifier to a function or not (just like int values referred by identifiers or as constant in code).

-----EDIT----- suggested by @bacjist

If you don't want to use lambda, then you may define the function as usual:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

and then call:

```
print(maxf(f,[1,3]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just learned about lambda with this post, so I don't think i can use it on my exercises and I don't know why, because I see that it is really useful when working with functions.

Comment: Perhaps you want to propose a solution without lambda as well: `def fn(x):   return x**2  print(maxf(fn,[1,3]))`